# How to send List of Objects to kafka topic using spring-kafka framework?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

Me using spring-kafka in spring-boot application to send the data topic.
I need to fetch the data from a oracle table and send it.

I fetch List from oracle table. How to send them to topic ?

i.e.

1. Is there any way to send them as a List ?  if yes how ?
   If yes, then how to deserialize it at consumer side ?
2. Is it possible to send data like a streaming fashion using spring-book and spring-kafka ? if yes any more info or sample/snippet  plz ...

**How to handle partitionKey if I send List at a time?**

Currently I am sending individual Company obj hence have key defined as below

```
companyKafkaTemplate.send(COMPANY_TOPIC,this.getKey(company), company);
```

Comment: Why can't you use Kafka Connect to send database rows to Kafka? If you absolutely must write your own producer code, don't send a list of rows as one message to Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 , thank you , i have another wrapper/project which fetches data from underlying database tables , once i pull those list of records/objects  I need to send using spring-kafka send method , so seeking advice how to do.. how to multiple records parallel to the topic  , any actor frame work needed or spring is enough?

Answer (score 1):

For a `List` serialization and deserialization I would suggest to use a `JSON` support in Spring Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#serdes

For a *streaming* I would suggest to take a look into a Reactive support in Spring Kafka, based on the Reactor Kafka project: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka

For that purpose we provide a `ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate` and `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate`.

Comment: thank you , you mean List of objects ? or should those wrap into another object ? if List of object then how to serde them ?

Comment: That’s pretty enough to send as a list, without any wrapping. Not sure what is wrong with my suggestion about JSON (de)serialization...

Comment: Given link https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#serdes     I dont see any send method version to support  list , i.e takes list as argument. so i am bit confused . In the plain kafka we have but not in spring-kafka it seems

Comment: I'm confused. you just use a `KafkaTemplate.send()` with your `List<?>`. The `JsonSerializer` takes care about the proper list and its items serialization. What do you mean with "we have in plain Kafka"?

Comment: thank ..here I mean we are not using kafka stream and etc ...only kafka core i.e. spring-kafka...   If we send list of Objects how Kafka determine the partitionKey ..whose logic I written based on object fields i.e.    "" companyInfoKafkaTemplate.send(COMPANY_INFO_TOPIC_NAME,this.getKey(companyInfoRecord), companyInfoRecord);  """?  so how to handle it when I pass list of objects ?

Comment: please check "How to handle partitionKey if I send List<Company> at a time?" section in question

Comment: There is not distinguishing in Kafka between a single record and a list. The list is going to be treated as a single record as well. So, you need to iterate your list and use `KafkaTemplate.send()` for each item in that list. The Kafka client has an ability to buffer records in the producer and then flush them all at once for better performance, but it still is not about end-user API for sending a single list. So, your question is not relevant to Apache Kafka API: it just just impossible. And I think it was don't deliberately because of that `partitionKey` functionality.

Comment: thank you , so ultimately we send one by one obj in the list to using send() .... When I use list , I need to serde right ? how can I serde ? should I serde whole List object at once , hope it is not feasible.

Comment: You jus configure a `ProducerFactory` with an appropriate serializer for that list items. How you may send items separately if you would serialize the whole list?